# Creating indexed lists of solutions using Do Command

Tags: equation-solving, list-manipulation, procedural-programming

Why when I perform this code am I not producing lists called roots[j], each containing 3 elements which are the roots of the equation?

When I type roots[0] for example I get roots[0] as answer instead of 3 different roots.

```
Do[roots[a] = z/.NSolve[z^3 + 3 z^2 - z == a, z]], {a, -15, 
15, 0.1}];
```

Note: I made a similar question a while ago and it was closed as I made a typo error. This is the correct code which for some reason does not work. I still do not understand why when I write roots[2.4] for example that I don't get the 3 roots written in a list.

Comment: Memoization would probably solve your problem in a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `a` isn't actually *exactly* incrementing by `0.1` every time.  So `roots[2.4]` doesn't actually have a defined value.

If we take a look at the `InputForm` of the arguments for the defined values of `roots`, then this becomes apparent.

```
Cases[DownValues[roots], HoldPattern[roots[x_]] :> x, ∞] // InputForm // Short
```

> {-15., -14.9, -14.8, -14.7, -14.6, -14.5, -14.4, -14.3, -14.2, -14.1, -14., -13.9, -13.8, -13.7, -13.6, -13.5, <<277>>, 14.3, 14.400000000000002, 14.5, 14.600000000000001, 14.700000000000003, 14.8, 14.900000000000002, 15.}

**One** way to get around this is to use exact numbers/rationals in the assignment, and then rationalize the input.

```
Do[roots[a] = z /. NSolve[z^3 + 3 z^2 - z == a, z], {a, -15, 15, 1/10}]
roots[2.4 // Rationalize]
```

> {-3.07116, -0.849142, 0.920299}

Comment: Why doesn't it increment by 0.1 every time when I ask it to?

Answer (score 2):

[Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) as a form of [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) may do what you need:

```
Clear[roots];
roots[a_?NumericQ] := roots[a] = z /. NSolve[z^3 + 3 z^2 - z == a, z]
```

Asking for a value now computes it and stores (caches) the result:

```
roots[2.4]
(*    {-3.07116, -0.849142, 0.920299}    *)
```

So there's no need to pre-compute a list of these.

Look at all the cached results:

```
?roots
(*    list of definition and cached results    *)
```